# With three.js, can I attach vertex metadata information in a Geometry object

Tags: angular, typescript, three.js

I have a THREE.Geometry object that is actually a merged version of geometries of all the meshes in a THREE.Group. I need to attach metadata to each vertex in the merged THREE.Geometry object i.e. the mesh-id (from the group) etc.

The goal is to attach this metadata and keep it intact when merging geometries.

```
private merge(groupObject: any): THREE.Geometry {
    const editableGroupObject = _.cloneDeep(groupObject);
    const mergedGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    const uniqueMaterials: THREE.Material[] = [];

    for (const childMesh of editableGroupObject.children) {
        mergedGeometry.merge(childMesh.geometry);
    }
    return mergedGeometry;
}
```

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.. Why do you need it to be `THREE.Geometry`? `THREE.BufferGeometry` is recommended, and does support vertex attributes. If the problem is related to merging, you can convert back to BufferGeometry at the end or use [BufferGeometryUtils](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/BufferGeometryUtils).

Comment: There isn't a vertex metadata. You might be able to encode it in the color channel of your vertices somehow..

Or you might maintain a separate map with the regions.
FWIW, I think the geometry merging doesn't change the layout of faces, so you can count on the the vertex ranges for each joined part, remaining contiguous.. so if you check the vertex count before and after the merge, that's the index range of that part. Keep an array of those, keyed with the UUID of the merged geometry, and you can then use it to decipher part number from vertex index.